# How to understand big o time of a given code

Tags: matlab, time, computation

I am observing a built in function in Matlab, which is "boundary". It was introduced in 2014b and it is to compute the boundary for a given set of points. Nevertheless, I need to know big o (time complexity) of this function. How can I understand it, could you guide me to a source.
Best

Comment: Use [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to measure time used by the function?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what algorithm they use. Convex hull in 2d is `O(n log n)`, so it's at least that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tic` and `toc` to get the time and run for increasingly larger systems then try to fit the data to the standards (n, n log n, n^2, ...).

Comment: I used tic toc, and concluded that "boundary" takes longer than convhull. S